# How do I get a directional light's (e.g. Sun's) Y axis position in a UI Widget in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-5

I have a UI widget that will be tracking the in-game position of the sun (bottom left corner).

[image: In-game screenshot featuring sun dial]

When I try to get the sun's position, it can't find the sun actor even though (I think) I have a reference to it in the widget blueprint.

[image]

[image: SunDial widget blueprint]

All I get is a null reference error.

[image: Null reference error for Sun actor screenshot]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: How are you setting sun actor? I cannot see any event called that set the value of the actors. It seems that you didn't executed at begin play and as tick starts the value of SunActor is still null

Comment: @SimoneLungarella, I'm using the Get All Actors with Tag and setting the tag to "Sun", then using a GET node to select the 0 index and using a Set node to set the actor variable. I currently only have one actor with that tag in my project, so the 0 index should get me the Sun...but it's not.

Comment: I see the code you are talking about but no one is calling it, you should link it to an event like BeginPlay to trigger it before the tick starts

Comment: That was it, @SimoneLungarella. If you want to make that an official answer, I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event that initialize your SunActor is required. The node `GetAllActorsWithTag` has an exec pin and it required to be linked to something. For example it can be linked to the begin play event that triggers before your tick event:

[image: example]